# Calcular Horas Totais, identificando Intervalos de tempo iguais

Tags: sql, sql-server, lógica, sql-server-2005

depois de quebrar um pouco a cabeça, peço ajuda dos senhores para auxiliar na seguinte situação:

Estou com um problema no SQL (Sql Server 2005) de calculo de horas;
Basicamente tenho que calcular a soma de horas trabalhadas em acionamentos técnicos.

A questão é que um acionamento pode ocorrer enquanto o outro ainda estiver aberto, e atrapalhar na hora da soma total da pessoa.

Ex:

- Acionamento 1: 06/03 12:00 ---a--- 06/03 19:00
- Acionamento 2: 06/03 13:00 ---a--- 06/03 15:00
- Acionamento 3: 06/03 20:00 ---a--- 06/03 22:00

O total de tempo correto, neste caso seriam 9 horas, pois o segundo acionamento não conta por estar dentro do primeiro; Mas se eu fizer pelo método de subtração normal do SQL, irá resultar errado.

Alguém já fez alguma coisa desse tipo? Calcular a maior data final - menor data inicial também não funcionaria, pois estaríamos contando os intervalos entre os acionamentos juntos (no exemplo o intervalo entre o 1 e 3).

A base gera justamente a data e hora separada, junto também com o numero (1ª,2º,3ª...) do acionamento. No máximo são 7 acionamentos.

Obrigado desde já!

Fiz a tabela de exemplo para ficar mais fácil:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
    ID_ENTRADA INTEGER, 
    MATRICULA_COLABORADOR INTEGER, 
    DATA_AUTORIZACAO VARCHAR(50),
    DATA_INICIO_HE VARCHAR(50),
    HORA_INICIO_HE VARCHAR(50), 
    DATA_TERMINO_HE VARCHAR(50), 
    HORA_TERMINO_HE VARCHAR(50), 
    QUANTIDADE_HE VARCHAR(50), 
    ACIONAMENTO INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tabela values (1, 100, '09/03/2015', '14/03/2015', '14:00:00', '14/03/2015', '16:00:00', '02:00:00', 1);
INSERT INTO tabela values (2, 100, '09/03/2015', '14/03/2015', '15:30:00', '14/03/2015', '17:00:00', '01:30:00', 2);
INSERT INTO tabela values (3, 100, '09/03/2015', '14/03/2015', '19:00:00', '14/03/2015', '22:00:00', '02:00:00', 3);
INSERT INTO tabela values (4, 100, '09/03/2015', '15/03/2015', '08:00:00', '15/03/2015', '10:00:00', '02:00:00', 1);
INSERT INTO tabela values (5, 100, '09/03/2015', '15/03/2015', '08:30:00', '15/03/2015', '10:30:00', '02:00:00', 2);
```

Exemplo no [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f5ff/1/0)

**Resumindo:** Quero que apresente a hora total trabalhada por essa matricula: 8:30:00

Comment: Poderia por favor editar sua pergunta colocando algum SQL e a estrutura das tabelas utilizadas para a consulta?

Comment: Pronto, espero que tenha ajudado...
Pensei em contar os minutos dentro do intervalo e depois concatenar DATA+HORA+MINUTO no acionamento 1 e comparar se esse mesmo padrão aparece no acionamento 2 ; Se aparecer, não contar esse minuto. @.@

Comment: Se por exemplo temos dois acionamentos no mesmo dia, sendo um começado 9h e terminando 14h, e outro começando 11h e terminando 15h30, como ficaria a hora de início, a hora de término e a quantidade de horas?

Comment: Acionamento 01   
data_inicio: 10/03/2015 9:00:00   
data_final: 10/03/2015 14:00:00   
quantidade_he: 05:00   
 
 
acionamento 02:   
data_inicio: 10/03/2015 11:00:00   
data_final: 10/03/2015 15:30:00   
quantidade_he: 04:30   
   
----------> SOMA DE HORAS DE ACIONAMENTO: 06:30 <---------

Comment: Sim, mas pelo que eu entendi não podem aparecer os dois acionamentos, certo? Seria um registro só com a menor hora e a maior hora. Ou seria outra coisa?

Comment: O objetivo é só calcular a soma de horas de acionamento de cada MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, não importa se não mostrar a quantidade de acionamentos que ele teve; Se o total de horas de acionamento estiver correto, tudo ok.

Comment: Uma duvida, você está modelando está tabela, ou ele já está em produção (funcionando em algum sistema)? Por que não usar `DateTime`? Eu não entendo de SqlServer, mas suponho que além de uma query mais simples, você ainda teria um perfomance bem melhor (me corrija se eu estiver enganado).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma procedure e nessa procedure calcular o tempo.
Nunca trabalhei com sql server, então não sei como criar essa procedure e muito provavelmente minha query não é a mais adequada, mas você pode ter ideias como melhorá-la.

Mas a sql que usei para conseguir os 30600 segundos equivalente a 8.5 horas foi essa.

```
declare @temp table (id INTEGER, data_ini datetime, data_fim datetime);

insert into @temp
select ID_ENTRADA,
convert(datetime, DATA_INICIO_HE + ' ' +HORA_INICIO_HE, 103),
convert(datetime, DATA_TERMINO_HE + ' ' +HORA_TERMINO_HE, 103)
from tabela;

declare @curid int;
declare @maxid int;
declare @data_ini datetime;
declare @data_fim datetime;

select @curid = min(id), @maxid = max(id) from @temp;

while @curid <= @maxid
begin
    select 
    @data_ini = data_ini, 
    @data_fim = data_fim 
    from @temp where id = @curid;

    update @temp set data_ini = (select min(data_ini) FROM @temp where data_fim between @data_ini and @data_fim) where id = @curid;
    delete from @temp where data_fim between @data_ini and @data_fim and id > @curid;

    update @temp set data_fim = (select max(data_fim) FROM @temp where data_ini between @data_ini and @data_fim) where id = @curid;
    delete from @temp where data_ini between @data_ini and @data_fim and id > @curid;

    delete from @temp where 
    data_ini between @data_ini and @data_fim and 
    data_fim between @data_ini and @data_fim and
    id <> @curid;

    select @curid = min(id) from @temp where id > @curid;
end

select SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, data_ini, data_fim)) from @temp
```

[o exemplo você pode encontrar aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f5ff/204)

esse código também funciona

```
declare @temp table (id INTEGER, data_ini datetime, data_fim datetime);

insert into @temp
select ID_ENTRADA,
convert(datetime, DATA_INICIO_HE + ' ' +HORA_INICIO_HE, 103),
convert(datetime, DATA_TERMINO_HE + ' ' +HORA_TERMINO_HE, 103)
from tabela;

select sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND, m, m2))  from (
  select distinct
  (select min(t2.data_ini) from @temp as t2 where t.data_ini between t2.data_ini and t2.data_fim or t.data_fim between t2.data_ini and t2.data_fim) as m,
  (select max(t2.data_fim) from @temp as t2 where t.data_ini between t2.data_ini and t2.data_fim or t.data_fim between t2.data_ini and t2.data_fim) as m2
  from @temp as t
) a
```

nesse segundo código usei uma tabela secundaria apenas porque estava com preguiça de ficar convertendo sempre as data.

[exemplo você pode encontrar aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0a0b9/1)

Answer (score 4):

A coisa já começa estranha por data e hora estarem em colunas separadas e serem do tipo varchar(?)(estou supondo que sim).

Eu agrupei conforme o que eu entendi, que era pegar a menor hora de um acionamento e a maior data de um acionamento e calcular a quantidade de tempo neles. Se for algo diferene disso, por favor explicar melhor.

- [Exemplo funcional no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dda8/1)

Como não cabe nos comentários, minha sugestão:

```
select MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, ACIONAMENTO, 
  convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103) as data_hora_inicio_minimo, 
  convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103) as data_hora_termino_maximo, 
  concat(
    format(datediff(
      second, 
      convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103), 
      convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103)
    ) / 60 / 60, '00'), ':', 
    format(datediff(
      second, 
      convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103), 
      convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103)
    ) / 60 % 60, '00') , ':',
     format(datediff(
      second, 
      convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103), 
      convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103)
    ) % 60, '00')
  ) as tempo
from tabela 
group by MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, ACIONAMENTO;
```

edit (li nos comentarios que voce queria a somátoria por matricula), ainda usando o sql acima:

```
select MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, SUM(segundos) as total_segundos, 
concat(
    format(SUM(segundos) / 60 / 60, '00'), ':', 
    format(SUM(segundos) / 60 % 60, '00') , ':',
    format(SUM(segundos) % 60, '00')
  ) as total_tempo   
from (select MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, ACIONAMENTO, 
  convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103) as data_hora_inicio_minimo, 
  convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103) as data_hora_termino_maximo, 
  concat(
    format(datediff(
      second, 
      convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103), 
      convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103)
    ) / 60 / 60, '00'), ':', 
    format(datediff(
      second, 
      convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103), 
      convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103)
    ) / 60 % 60, '00') , ':',
     format(datediff(
      second, 
      convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103), 
      convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103)
    ) % 60, '00')
  ) as tempo, datediff(
      second, 
      convert(datetime, MIN(DATA_INICIO_HE) + ' ' + MIN(HORA_INICIO_HE), 103), 
      convert(datetime, MAX(DATA_TERMINO_HE) + ' ' + MAX(HORA_TERMINO_HE), 103)
    ) segundos
from tabela 
group by MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, ACIONAMENTO) as temp group by MATRICULA_COLABORADOR;
```

Se for isso, me avise para que eu possa melhorar o sql final.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f5ff/1/0 - Infelizmente FORMAT não funciona no SQL-SERVER 2005. fiz o fiddle pra simular e você entender. Quero que mostre o tempo total trabalhado pelo funcionário, 08:30:00.

Comment: o format a gente deixa por ultimo. agora que eu entendi melhor, nem o sql que eu te passei acima estaria certo para seu caso rs. Me diz uma coisa, no seu primeiro exemplo de 9 horas, se houvesse o quarto acionamento das 21:30 as 22:30 só seria contado mais meia hora ?

Comment: Exato. Pois já tinha um aberto as 20:00 com fechamento menor que abertura do 4º acionamento :)

Answer (score 2):

[Para esta resposta, estou usando este SQLFiddle, fornecido pelo autor da pergunta](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f5ff/31).

A sentença ficou assim:

```
SELECT MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, DATA_AUTORIZACAO, DATA_INICIO_HE, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN(T.HORA_INICIO), 108) AS HORA_INICIO_HE, 
    DATA_TERMINO_HE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MAX(T.HORA_TERMINO), 108) AS HORA_TERMINO,
  (DATEDIFF(second, MIN(T.HORA_INICIO), MAX(T.HORA_TERMINO)) * 1.0) / 3600 AS QUANTIDADE_HE 
  FROM (
    SELECT MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, DATA_AUTORIZACAO, DATA_INICIO_HE, 
    CONVERT(datetime, DATA_INICIO_HE + ' ' + HORA_INICIO_HE, 103) AS HORA_INICIO, 
    DATA_TERMINO_HE, CONVERT(datetime, DATA_TERMINO_HE + ' ' + HORA_TERMINO_HE, 103) AS HORA_TERMINO
FROM TABELA) T
GROUP BY T.MATRICULA_COLABORADOR, T.DATA_AUTORIZACAO, T.DATA_INICIO_HE, T.DATA_TERMINO_HE;
```

Está devolvendo a quantidade de horas como decimal, mas acredito que deva ser suficiente pra resposta.

Comment: Então, é realmente um começo, obrigado - Mas a questão principal é que essa não soluciona a questão dos acionamentos múltiplos.

Comment: Você quer que apareça todos os acionamentos?

Comment: Não. Não preciso, só preciso do HORARIO TOTAL certo.

Comment: O que estaria diferente? O que era esperado e o que a sentença gerou? Pode por favor complementar sua pergunta com essas informações?

Comment: Oi, editei a pergunta e coloquei um SQLfiddle, veja se consegue entender melhor. OBRIGADO!

Comment: @DHEKU Fiz uma consulta baseada no seu Fiddle. Veja se está ok.

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de propor uma solução:

Eu faria com uma tabela auxiliar, totalizadora, algo assim:

```
MATRICULA | HORA_INICIO          | HORA_FIM | ACIONAMENTO
XXX       | INICIO_ACIONAMENTO 1 |  NULL    | 1
```

Ao abrir o primeiro acionamento preencho o valor no campo hora inicio, e incremento a coluna acionamento, a cada acionamento novo incremento o totalizador de acionamentos, se existir algum ativo, caso não exista crie um novo registro.

Ao fechar um acionamento, decremento a coluna acionamento, se chegar a zero, fechei todos abertos e posso finalizar este registro.

Ao abrir um acionamento sem nenhum registro aberto aqui, adiciono um novo.

Faço o total por esta tabela.

Acho um caminho mais viável, a verificação dos dados nesta tabela pode ser feito por trigger na outra.